# UML Class Diagram from Node.js Express based app?

Tags: node.js, web, uml, class-diagram

Does anyone ever worked on making Class Diagram (UML) from Node.js Express based app? We built web app as semestral work but Teacher said he wants Class Diagram for it :D I know Class diagram is the thing from what you make the app but we need to do it oppositely.
Should I just say that controllers, services, models, routers (generally javascript modules) are classes and just connect them how they are in HTTP lifetime?

I tried npm module called WAWI but it's made for reverse engineering :D (Including everything, really everything)

Comment: Go and RE some sources with a tool like Enterprise Architect on your own and get happy with that.

Comment: Did you use TypeScript or JavaScript or both? Bear in mind that in JavaScript you write/code objects, not classes. So you'd want an object model for that.

Answer (score 3):

It would be good to ask your teacher *why* he wants a class diagram and *how he defines a class* in your context.

1. A class is a module. This is what you mentioned in your question. If your teacher wants the class diagram to get insight in the structure of the application, then I would recommend this definition.
2. A class is a Typescript class or Javascript prototype. This probably leads to too many classes. If there are complex datastructures in the app, it may be good to have a separate class diagram depicting the datastructure(s).
3. A class is a conceptual entity recognizable by the end-user. The class diagram shows the concepts the end-user is interested in and their relationships. This kind of class diagram is used to gain insight into the structural aspect of the functionality of the application, regardless its technical structure.
4. If you have an underlying database: a class is a table (if you have a relational db) or a persistent class (if you have an object db).